# Match common values and copy to the corresponding cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Sample of the data
[image]

The left column (E) of email addresses is quite long 10,000+ and is in no particular order, with it's corresponding country (F).
The right column of email addresses (H) is a fraction of the size however it contains many duplicate values.

I need to compare all of the values in **E** with all of the values in **H**, if there is a match copy the value in **F** to the corresponding cell in **I**.

I've looked into Vlookup, VBA scripts and if formulas.

Comment: Is it possible to be more mails from "E:E" column matching with the one in column "H:H"? If so, how to proceed for such a case? To return the first match, or all cases, if the country is different? Or cannot  such a situation be possible?

Comment: It's not possible I have already removed duplicate values from E. There will be more values in E then in H but there will only be 1 match.

I can compare the 2 columns and identify which are duplicates I'm just unsure of how to copy the country then to the corresponding duplicate.

Comment: OK. I will place an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and working mostly in memory should be very fast:

```
Sub ExtractMatchingCountry()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRowE As Long, lastRowH As Long, arrEF, arrHI, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRowE = sh.Range("E" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last cell in E:E
 lastRowH = sh.Range("H" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last cell in H:H
 
 arrEF = sh.Range("E2:F" & lastRowE).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
 arrHI = sh.Range("H2:I" & lastRowH).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration/processing
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrEF)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrHI)
        If arrEF(i, 1) = arrHI(j, 1) Then
            arrHI(j, 2) = arrEF(i, 2): Exit For
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 'drop the processed array content to the range:
 sh.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrHI), 2).value = arrHI
End Sub
```

Is there a possibility that the strings to be compared to look the same but some letters to be in Upper case against Lower? If so, I can adapt the code to handle such a situation, too. Now, it compares the **identic strings**. I mean "john.doe@yahoo.com" is not the same with "John.doe@yahoo.com"...